# how can i use pip search with my own nexus pypi repo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, pip, nexus

I deploy a nexus repo sys in my local area network, and I config a PyPI repo on it. I can use `pip install` to install package with my private mirror. But I cannot use `pip search`.

Here is my pip.ini

```
[global]
index-url = http://nexus.repo.com/repository/PyPI/simple
index = http://nexus.repo.com/repository/PyPI/pypi
trusted-host = nexus.repo.com
```

And when I use `pip search` it returns:

> C:\Users\user>pip search redis
>   HTTP error 404 while getting http://nexus.repo.com/repository/PyPI/pypi
>   Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\search.py", line 45, in run pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
>     File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\search.py", line 62, in search hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
>     File "c:\python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in **call** return self.__send(self.__name, args)
>     File "c:\python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request verbose=self.__verbose
>     File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 776, in request response.raise_for_status()
>     File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\models.py", line 862, in raise_for_status raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
>   HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url:http://nexus.repo.com/repository/PyPI/pypi
>       C:\Users\user>

I'm googling and googling, but coming up empty so far.
So here I am, hoping someone else can guide me through this.
thank you very much.

Comment: But you can install/download from that url? Try `pip download mypkg --index http://nexus.repo.com/repository/PyPI/pypi`, do you get the package downloaded? Also, what do you need `trusted-host` for if you don't use SSL anyway?

Comment: Yes, Dude. I can `pip download` and `pip install` from my repo, but I cannot `pip search` packages.
And I intend to use SSL after figured the problem. So I add trust host to configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:
pip search redis -i http://nexus.repo.com/repository/PyPI/pypi -vvv --trusted-host nexus.repo.com

I had the same problem, and found that I was basically searching with the /simple url, rather than the /pypi one (the /simple one works only for pip install)

Comment: already tried. but doesn't work for me.  i set config `index = http://nexus.repo.com/repository/PyPI/pypi` which means `pip search redis -i http://nexus.repo.com/repository/PyPI/pypi -vvv --trusted-host nexus.repo.com`. rigth?

Comment: This is working for me `pip search --index https://nexus.repo.com:8081/repository/my-pypi/pypi  --trusted-host nexus.repo.com:8081 my-package`

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was that I used the simple URL `https://pypi.org/simple/` for the `Remote Storage` parameter when setting up the proxy repository instead of `https://pypi.org/`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that this feature [was deprecated](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/pypi-repositories#PyPIRepositories-BrowsingPyPIRepositoriesandSearchingPackages) for proxied repositories.

> "pip search" command is deprecated and doesn't work with a proxy repository, but you can still search for packages in hosted repositories.